# Conectar banco de dados Sql Server ao Programa ios Swfit

Tags: ios, swift

Existe alguma forma de usar o banco de dados sql server no ios ? eu uso a lib jtds no android e consigo fazer a conexão mas no ios?

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer acessar um banco de dados externo diretamente do iOS, não será possível. Você precisa se comunicar com um web service, e este web service sim se conecta com o banco de dados para fazer as consultas/atualizações.

Já se você quer persistir dados localmente no device, você pode usar umas das soluções específicas, como Core Data ou SQLite.